# The bit from Armstrong's book on Group Theory; Theorem 10.2

Tags: group-theory

The below is the theorem concerned, and the bit in red I have circled I cannot understand.[image]

Issue is, it says "if." Well yes, "if" it is true hen indeed $xy=x'y'$. But has it been proved that that is always the case?
I ask this because a past paper problem essentially asks me to (in the context of Armstrong's $10.2$)

> 1. Prove that any $g \in G$ has a unique form of $g=hk$
> 2. Prove theorem $10.2$

Clearly I was stuck in doing both and $2$ is answered as shown in the book...but I cannot figure out how $1$ can be proved. The solution just says "look at theorem $10.2$ from Armstrong" so I was assuming it would be answered here...
I essentially understand the rest of the argument though.

Am I missing it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to consider the case "if not". The "if" argument shows the homomorphism $\varphi$ is injective.

Comment: Uhm, so when asked "prove $g=hk$ is unique for $h,k$" I answer "if it is unique then it is unique, so it *is* unique"........?

Comment: No, 1 follows from the fact that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. Recall that $f \colon X \to Y$ is injective if for any $x, x' \in X$ that $f(x) = f(x')$ we have $x=x'$.